# C++ thread using function object, how are multiple destructors are called but not the constructors?

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

Please find the code snippet below:

```
class tFunc{
    int x;
    public:
    tFunc(){
        cout<<"Constructed : "<<this<<endl;
        x = 1;
    }
    ~tFunc(){
        cout<<"Destroyed : "<<this<<endl;
    }
    void operator()(){
        x += 10;
        cout<<"Thread running at : "<<x<<endl;
    }
    int getX(){ return x; }
};

int main()
{
    tFunc t;
    thread t1(t);
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"Thread is joining..."<<endl;
        t1.join();
    }
    cout<<"x : "<<t.getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Constructed : 0x7ffe27d1b0a4
Destroyed : 0x7ffe27d1b06c
Thread is joining...
Thread running at : 11
Destroyed : 0x2029c28
x : 1
Destroyed : 0x7ffe27d1b0a4
```

I am confused how the destructors with address 0x7ffe27d1b06c and 0x2029c28 called and no constructors were called? Whereas the first and last constructor and destructor respectively are of the object I created.

Comment: Define and instrument your copy-ctor and move-ctor as well.

Comment: Well, understood. Since I am passing the object the copy constructor being called, am I correct? But, when is the move constructor called?

Answer (score 19):

You are missing instrumenting copy-construction and move construction. A simple modification to your program will provide evidence that is where the constructions are taking place.

**Copy Constructor**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class tFunc{
    int x;
public:
    tFunc(){
        cout<<"Constructed : "<<this<<endl;
        x = 1;
    }
    tFunc(tFunc const& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
    }

    ~tFunc(){
        cout<<"Destroyed : "<<this<<endl;
    }

    void operator()(){
        x += 10;
        cout<<"Thread running at : "<<x<<endl;
    }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    tFunc t;
    thread t1{t};
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"Thread is joining..."<<endl;
        t1.join();
    }
    cout<<"x : "<<t.getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary)

```
Constructed : 0x104055020
Copy constructed : 0x104055160 (source=0x104055020)
Copy constructed : 0x602000008a38 (source=0x104055160)
Destroyed : 0x104055160
Thread running at : 11
Destroyed : 0x602000008a38
Thread is joining...
x : 1
Destroyed : 0x104055020
```

---

**Copy Constructor and Move Constructor**

If you provide a move ctor it will be preferred for at least one of those otherwise-copies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class tFunc{
    int x;
public:
    tFunc(){
        cout<<"Constructed : "<<this<<endl;
        x = 1;
    }
    tFunc(tFunc const& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
    }

    tFunc(tFunc&& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Move constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
        obj.x = 0;
    }

    ~tFunc(){
        cout<<"Destroyed : "<<this<<endl;
    }

    void operator()(){
        x += 10;
        cout<<"Thread running at : "<<x<<endl;
    }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    tFunc t;
    thread t1{t};
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"Thread is joining..."<<endl;
        t1.join();
    }
    cout<<"x : "<<t.getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary)

```
Constructed : 0x104057020
Copy constructed : 0x104057160 (source=0x104057020)
Move constructed : 0x602000008a38 (source=0x104057160)
Destroyed : 0x104057160
Thread running at : 11
Destroyed : 0x602000008a38
Thread is joining...
x : 1
Destroyed : 0x104057020
```

---

**Reference Wrapped**

If you want to avoid those copies you can  wrap your callable in a reference wrapper (`std::ref`). Since you want to utilize `t` after the threading part is done, this is viable for your situation. In practice you must be *very* careful when threading against references to call objects, as lifetime of the object must extend at least as long as the thread utilizing the reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class tFunc{
    int x;
public:
    tFunc(){
        cout<<"Constructed : "<<this<<endl;
        x = 1;
    }
    tFunc(tFunc const& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
    }

    tFunc(tFunc&& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Move constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
        obj.x = 0;
    }

    ~tFunc(){
        cout<<"Destroyed : "<<this<<endl;
    }

    void operator()(){
        x += 10;
        cout<<"Thread running at : "<<x<<endl;
    }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    tFunc t;
    thread t1{std::ref(t)}; // LOOK HERE
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"Thread is joining..."<<endl;
        t1.join();
    }
    cout<<"x : "<<t.getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary)

```
Constructed : 0x104057020
Thread is joining...
Thread running at : 11
x : 11
Destroyed : 0x104057020
```

Note even though I kept the copy-ctor and move-ctor overloads, neither were called, as the reference wrapper is now the thing being copy/moved; not the thing it references. Also, this final approach delivers what you were probably looking for; `t.x` back in `main` is, in fact, modified to `11`. It was not in the prior attempts. Can't stress this enough, however: *be careful doing this*. Object lifetime is *critical*.

---

**Move, And Nothing But**

Finally, if you have no interest in retaining `t` as you have in your example, you can use move semantics to send the instance straight to the thread, moving along the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class tFunc{
    int x;
public:
    tFunc(){
        cout<<"Constructed : "<<this<<endl;
        x = 1;
    }
    tFunc(tFunc const& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
    }

    tFunc(tFunc&& obj) : x(obj.x)
    {
        cout<<"Move constructed : "<<this<< " (source=" << &obj << ')' << endl;
        obj.x = 0;
    }

    ~tFunc(){
        cout<<"Destroyed : "<<this<<endl;
    }

    void operator()(){
        x += 10;
        cout<<"Thread running at : "<<x<<endl;
    }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    thread t1{tFunc()}; // LOOK HERE
    if(t1.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"Thread is joining..."<<endl;
        t1.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary)

```
Constructed : 0x104055040
Move constructed : 0x104055160 (source=0x104055040)
Move constructed : 0x602000008a38 (source=0x104055160)
Destroyed : 0x104055160
Destroyed : 0x104055040
Thread is joining...
Thread running at : 11
Destroyed : 0x602000008a38
```

Here you can see the object is created, the rvalue reference to said-same then sent straight to `std::thread::thread()`, where it is moved again to its final resting place, owned by the thread from that point forward. No copy-ctors are involved. The actual dtors are against two shells and the final-destination concrete object.

Answer (score 5):

As for your additional question posted in comments:

> When is the move constructor called?

The constructor of `std::thread` first creates a copy of its first argument (by [`decay_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)) — that is where *copy constructor* is called. (Note that in case of an *rvalue* argument, such as `thread t1{std::move(t)};` or `thread t1{tFunc{}};`, *move constructor* would be called instead.)

The result of `decay_copy` is a **temporary** that resides on the stack. However, since `decay_copy` is performed by a *calling thread*, this temporary resides on its stack and is destroyed at the end of `std::thread::thread` constructor. Consequently, the temporary itself cannot be used by a new created thread directly.

To "pass" the functor to the new thread, a new object needs to be created *somewhere else*, and this is where *move constructor* is invoked. (If it did not exist, copy constructor would be invoked instead.)

---

Note that we might wonder why *deferred temporary materialization* is not applied here. For instance, in this [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t7nEQESs27JaVX0i), only one constructor is invoked instead of two. I believe that some internal implementation details of the implementation of the C++ Standard library hinder the optimization to be applied for `std::thread` constructor.